# How can I calculate an average of a nested list while still keeping it associated with a string

Tags: python, nested-lists

I'm sorry if that didn't make any sense! I'm very new to python and I could really use some help.

I don't want the question to be solved for me, but I would appreciate some advice as a starting point.

```
    listA = [("Aleah", [74, 100, 120, 67]), 
             ("Hannah", [95, 110, 110, 67]), 
             ("Timothy", [71, 111, 98, 106])]
```

Essentially I need to find which person has the fastest average driving speed and then print their name.

How do I calculate the average of the second element in the list (also a list) while keeping it associated with the first element in the list (their name).

I don't even know where to begin, so any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What did you try yourself? Have you tried doing the task in your mind, breaking it down step by step and then thinking how to automate those steps?

Comment: If you want a very clean solution, look into `max()` and pay attention to it's `key` parameter, which can be a `lambda` that computes the average speed - but that approach may be a bit more advanced than a more straightforward approach with a simple `for` loop. This is why you should really try to solve it yourself first, so you don't end up with a really nice solution which you don't understand at all, but which just happens to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max` and its `key` parameter:

```
import statistics

def solve(lst):
    return max(lst, key=lambda v: statistics.mean(v[1]))[0]
```

This reads

- `max(...)`: calculate the maximum element of

  - `lst`: the list given as input
  - `key=...`: using as sorting key

    - `lambda v: ...`: a function that will be applied to each element `v` in `lst`, returning

      - `statistics.mean(v[1])`: the mean of the second element of `v`,
- `[0]`: and return its first element.

That said,

```
listA = [("Aleah", [74, 100, 120, 67]), ("Hannah", [95, 110, 110, 67]), ("Timothy", [71, 111, 98, 106])]
print(solve(listA))
```

will output Timothy.

You can read more about `max` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and read more about key functions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions).

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this may be below:

```
# creating class solution
class solution: 
    def __init__(self, name, value): 
        self.name = name 
        self.value = value
   
# creating list       
alist = [] 
avgList = []
  
# appending instances to list 
alist.append( solution('Aleah', [74, 100, 120, 67]) )
alist.append( solution('Hannah', [95, 110, 110, 67]) )
alist.append( solution('Timothy', [71, 111, 98, 106]) )
  
for obj in alist:
    avgList.append(sum(obj.value) / len(obj.value))

print(alist[avgList.index(max(avgList))].name, "has the fastest average speed.", sep =' ')
```